# How to properly load Bootstrap5's Masonry into Nuxt?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, bootstrap-5, masonry

I am trying to use the [Masonry plugin](https://masonry.desandro.com/) with Bootstrap5 and NuxtJS. When I follow the example here
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/examples/masonry/ and incorporate it into my own [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/nuxt-masonry-issue-fx7g6), I notice that my demo is not in the correct masonry format. See the gaps? **[My sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/nuxt-masonry-issue-fx7g6)**

> My example:

[image]

> Bootstrap's example:

[image]

What do I need to do to get my demo into format shown on the Bootstrap Masonry example page?

Comment: I found the issue (and some instances where it work), trying to fix it.

Comment: Not sure why I didn't see this before, but I noticed error in console: `210:627  error  failed to tokenize "\": true }\"...", expected attribute, ">" or "/>"  parser-error` for the masonry file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I checked how to load the script from a CDN either globally or locally. It was working but at one condition: you needed to **NOT** start on the masonry page.
Meaning that if you loaded the app on a specific page, then moved to the one with the masonry it was working. But not if you started on this specific page. So, a pretty subpar solution.

This article was really helpful to understand how to wait until the CDN script is fully loaded: https://vueschool.io/articles/vuejs-tutorials/how-to-load-third-party-scripts-in-nuxt-js/

Then I realized that we are far better installing it directly as an NPM dependency. Therefore, I proceeded to the [masonry](https://github.com/desandro/masonry) repo. Found [a great message](https://github.com/desandro/masonry/issues/1100#issuecomment-600993577) on how to setup the whole thing in Nuxt.

And after a removal of some useless stuff and some [modern dynamic import](https://javascript.info/modules-dynamic-imports#the-import-expression), here we are

```html
<template>
  <main>
    <h1>Bootstrap and Masonry</h1>

    <div class="row" id="masonry">
    <!-- ... -->
  </main>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  async mounted() {
    if (process.browser) {
      let { default: Masonry } = await import('masonry-layout')
      new Masonry('#masonry', { percentPosition: true })
    }
  },
}
</script>
```

The final solution is looking pretty well and there is not a lot of code. On top of that, the code is properly loaded. And you can load it on a click or any other event.

Comment: is `process.browser` still usable in NuxtJS v2.15.8? I am getting an error that `process is not defined` when using your code example. Also, would it be possible to take my codesandbox example from above and update it with your answer? I'm having some issues. Thanks.

Comment: @redshift hi, mind creating a new question?