# How to make a dynamic import in Nuxt?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, server-side-rendering, ace-editor

In my nuxt component I want to use the [ace editor](https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace):

```js
import Ace from "ace-builds/src-noconflict/ace"
```

when the component is mounted I am doing the following:

```js
this.editor = Ace.edit...
```

Obviously `the window is not defined` on the server on page reload. But unfortunately I just can't find a solution to fix this issue.

Is there a way to import a package on the `mounted()` hook?
I already tried

```js
const Ace = require("ace-builds/src-noconflict/ace")
```

But that doesn't quite seem to work. Do you have any ideas to solve this issue?

I already tried to register a plugin `plugins/ace.js`:

```js
import Vue from "vue"
import Ace from "ace-builds/src-noconflict/ace"
Vue.use(Ace)
```

registered it in `nuxt.config.js`:

```js
plugins: [
    { src: "~/plugins/ace", mode: "client" }
],
```

But how do I use Ace in my component now? It is still undefined...

Comment: As for the "client side" topic: [this part](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/directory-structure/plugins#client-or-server-side-only) of the plugin documentation should help

Comment: And you question how to access the plugin is answered [here](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/directory-structure/plugins#inject-in-root--context)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the error was thrown during the import statement, I'd recommended using [dynamic imports](https://v8.dev/features/dynamic-import) as explained in my [other answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67518659/how-to-properly-load-bootstrap5s-masonry-into-nuxt/67522750#67522750).

```js
async mounted() {
  if (process.client) {
    const Ace = await import('ace-builds/src-noconflict/ace')
    Ace.edit...
  }
},
```

From the official documentation: https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/internals-glossary/context

---

EDIT: I'm not sure about Ace and it's maybe a drastic change but you may also give a look to [vue-monaco](https://github.com/egoist/vue-monaco#use-esm-version-with-webpack) which is elbow-to-elbow popularity wise (vanilla Monaco editor).

EDIT2: `mounted` actually only runs on the client so you could strip the `process.client` conditional. Meanwhile, I do let it here in case you want to run some logic in other hooks like `created` (which are run on both server + client). More info [here](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/concepts/nuxt-lifecycle#client).

---

EDIT3: not directly related to the question, but some packages expose a component which is only available on the client-side (no SSR support), in those cases you could import the component only on the [client side](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69593428/8816585) and easily prevent any other errors.

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't work. The error gets thrown due to the import statement, not due to `Ace.edit`

Comment: Still, I have a minor question though. Since I am dynamically importing the package in my component now it only seems to work together with the plugin I stated in my inital question up above. So currently I am importing a package to my entire app even though I only need it in a single component. That doesn't look optimal :/

Comment: When you do **import** (and not **require**), Webpack will handle the tree-shaking of the editor. Even more, you could load on a click or a specific event. Until it's done, it will not be available globally into your app. So, actually this is the optimal way (to my knowledge) to import it into a single specific component. Using it as a Nuxt plugin will be the solution to use it globally through your app. Dynamic import => if you need it, import it. Require => import the **whole** package in any case. `require` is the bad boy and the old way of doing things.

Comment: Okay, so actually it should work by only importing it in the component, right? Somehow it doesn't make sense to me that I still need the nuxt plugin. Maybe I don't fully understand the concept of Nuxt here, but when I `console.log("hello")` in my nuxt plugin. It is logged on every route of my application. Therefor the package is imported on every single route (on page reload). That's what I meant with not optimal.

Comment: Haha, sorry to have not explained this directly. You can totally ditch the plugin if you **only** want to use it locally in your component. Plugins are indeed imported globally at the start of your app. Local import in the component => local usage, Nuxt plugin => global usage. Both => non sense.

Comment: Okay, so I still kind of have an issue here. 
1. If I only import the package in a plugin (globally), without dynamically importing it inside the component aswell, then `Ace is not defined`.
2. If I only import it dynamically inside my component, then `Ace is not defined`.
3. If I import it like every other package on top, then I get `window is not defined`
4. Only if I import it dynamically and in the plugin I don't get the error. That just doesn't make sense to me.

I hope you understand my struggle haha.

Comment: Isn't the 2. a matter of scope? Try changing it to `let Ace`, and get it out of the `mounted() ` scope and define it during the import if you're using it out of the `mounted() ` hook.

Answer (score 4):

**Nuxt Plugin**

IMHO you were on the right track with the "plugin" solution. Only mistake was the
`Vue.use(Ace)` part. This only works for [vue plugins](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/directory-structure/plugins#vue-plugins).

The plugin file could look somewhat like that:

```js
import Ace from 'ace-builds/src-noconflict/ace'
import Theme from 'ace-builds/src-noconflict/theme-monokai'

export default ({ app }, inject) => {
  inject('ace', {
    editor: Ace,
    theme: Theme
  })
}
```

Then you could use this plugin and initiate the editor in a component this way:

```html
<template>
  <div id="editor">
    function foo(items) {
    var x = "All this is syntax highlighted";
    return x;
    }
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data () {
    return {
      editor: {}
    }
  },
  mounted () {
    this.editor = this.$ace.editor.edit('editor')
    this.editor.setTheme(this.$ace.theme)
  }
}
</script>
```