# Error while integrating peerjs with nuxtjs (vue.js)

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, peerjs

installing:

> npm i peerjs

`/plugins/peerjs.js`

```js
import Peer from 'peerjs'

export default Peer
```

`nuxt.config.js`

```js
plugins: [
  { src: "~/plugins/peerjs.js", ssr: true }
],
```

Browser error:

> client.js?06a0:103 TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined
> (setting '_events')
> at i (peerjs.min.js?a0bc:46)
> at i (peerjs.min.js?a0bc:66)
> at _callee2$ (index.js?f26e:87)
> at tryCatch (runtime.js?96cf:63)
> at Generator.invoke [as _invoke] (runtime.js?96cf:294)
> at Generator.eval [as next] (runtime.js?96cf:119)
> at asyncGeneratorStep (asyncToGenerator.js?1da1:3)
> at _next (asyncToGenerator.js?1da1:25)
> _callee$ @ client.js?06a0:103 tryCatch @ runtime.js?96cf:63 invoke @ runtime.js?96cf:294 eval @ runtime.js?96cf:119 asyncGeneratorStep @
> asyncToGenerator.js?1da1:3
> _next @ asyncToGenerator.js?1da1:25 eval @ asyncToGenerator.js?1da1:32 eval @ asyncToGenerator.js?1da1:21 eval @ client.js?06a0:65
> Promise.catch (asíncrono) eval @ client.js?06a0:115 eval @
> client.js:1294 ./.nuxt/client.js @ app.js:35
> **webpack_require** @ runtime.js:854 fn @ runtime.js:151 0 @ app.js:9767
> **webpack_require** @ runtime.js:854 checkDeferredModules @ runtime.js:46 webpackJsonpCallback @ runtime.js:33 (anónimo) @
> app.js:1

Comment: It looks like Peerjs is not supported on the server actually:  https://github.com/peers/peerjs/issues/641 So, you should probably do the opposite aka `mode: 'client'`. Also, don't you need to do something else than just `import` and `export` it here. Also, please consider using it locally if you don't need it globally: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69593428/8816585 (and/or https://stackoverflow.com/a/69572014/8816585)

Comment: changing `ssr: true` to `mode: 'server'` seems to work, idk why

Comment: `ssr` is deprecated and should be replaced by `mode`. Then, `ssr: true` is saying that you want your plugin to be run both on server and on client. Meanwhile, since `peerjs` relies on `window` (only available in the browser), you need to only run it on the `'client'`. Not sure why your thing works with `'server'` tho. Your issue is solved? Mind if I post an answer then?

Comment: I understand your point, but it crashes on `client` and works on `server` kinda weird

Comment: What is the actual issue? Do you have an error or something?

Comment: No issues. Just got it working using `{ src: "~/plugins/peerjs.js" , mode:'server'},` instead of the sentence describdeon on question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting `{ src: '~/plugins/peerjs.js' , mode: 'server'}` fixed the issue.

Strange since it should either be `mode: 'client'` as shown in [the documentation](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/configuration-glossary/configuration-plugins#the-plugins-property) but I guess that PeerJS relies in fact on Node and not on client's window.