# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'controller') Swiper vue-awesome-swiper

Tags: nuxt.js, swiper.js

When I used 'Swiper' in nuxt.js and installed 'vue-awesome-swiper', I copied the thumbnail code from the official website, But I kept getting an error 'Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'controller')'. I changed the version as I found it, but it didn't solve the problem

```json
"swiper": "^7.4.1",
"vue-awesome-swiper": "^3.1.3",
```

```js
mounted() {
  this.$nextTick(() => {
    console.log(this.$refs.swiperTop.swiper);
    console.log(this.$refs.swiperThumbs.swiper);
    const swiperTop = this.$refs.swiperTop.$swiper;
    const swiperThumbs = this.$refs.swiperThumbs.$swiper;
    swiperTop.controller.control = swiperThumbs;
    swiperThumbs.controller.control = swiperTop;
  });
},
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using Swiper js with Nuxt throws dependency not found error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69643687/using-swiper-js-with-nuxt-throws-dependency-not-found-error)

Comment: @kissu Thank you, I don't have the answers in this thread, but I just found the solution somewhere else.

Comment: Did you got your issue solved? Feel free to accept it.

Answer (score 1):

```
"dependencies": {
    "nuxt": "^2.2.0",
    "swiper": "5",
    "vue-awesome-swiper": "^4.1.1",
}
```

I can report the same issue with the swiper property. According to the doc, I use the same code for a computed property for getting all the refs. In dev mode it works fine.

```
computed: {
      swiper() {
        return this.$refs.mySwiper.$swiper
      }
    }
```

But after deployment console shows the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'swiper').
```

So, as mentioned above I add $el for resolve this issue `this.$refs.mySwiper.$el.swiper`
Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
const swiperTop = this.$refs.swiperTop.$swiper;
const swiperThumbs = this.$refs.swiperThumbs.$swiper;
```

to

```
const swiperTop = this.$refs.swiperTop.$el.swiper
const swiperThumbs = this.$refs.swiperThumbs.$el.swiper
```