# InternalError: too much recursion after build - Nuxt JS

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, vercel, vue-good-table

I'm using vue-good-table and everything works in localhost. But after I take a look at my Vercel, I got an error **InternalError: too much recursion**

components/VueGoodTable.vue

```
<template>
  <div>
    <vue-good-table
      mode="remote"
      @on-search="onSearch"
      @on-page-change="onPageChange"
      @on-column-filter="onColumnFilter"
      @on-per-page-change="onPerPageChange"
      :totalRows="totalRecords"
      :isLoading.sync="isLoading"
      :pagination-options="{
        enabled: true,
        perPage: serverParams.perPage,
        dropdownAllowAll: false,
      }"
      :rows="rows"
      :columns="columns"
      :search-options="{
        enabled: true,
        searchFn: onSearch,
      }"
      :sort-options="{
        enabled: false,
      }"
    >
      <template slot="table-row" slot-scope="props">
        <span v-if="props.column.field == 'image'">
          <img
            :src="
              'https://waarungg.devryank.tech/public/images/' +
                pageActive +
                '/' +
                rows[props.index].image
            "
            width="100"
            class="mx-auto my-2"
          />
        </span>
        <span v-else-if="props.column.field == 'action'">
          <div class="flex">
            <div
              class="flex flex flex-auto justify-center content-center justify-center content-center"
              v-if="pageActive == 'orders' || pageActive == 'products'"
            >
              <nuxt-link
                :to="{
                  name: 'dashboard-' + pageActive + '-detail',
                  params: { detail: rows[props.index][slug] },
                }"
                ><svg
                  class="w-6 h-6"
                  fill="none"
                  stroke="currentColor"
                  viewBox="0 0 24 24"
                  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                >
                  <path
                    stroke-linecap="round"
                    stroke-linejoin="round"
                    stroke-width="2"
                    d="M15 12a3 3 0 11-6 0 3 3 0 016 0z"
                  ></path>
                  <path
                    stroke-linecap="round"
                    stroke-linejoin="round"
                    stroke-width="2"
                    d="M2.458 12C3.732 7.943 7.523 5 12 5c4.478 0 8.268 2.943 9.542 7-1.274 4.057-5.064 7-9.542 7-4.477 0-8.268-2.943-9.542-7z"
                  ></path></svg
              ></nuxt-link>
            </div>
            <div
              class="flex flex-auto justify-center content-center"
              v-if="pageActive == 'products'"
            >
              <nuxt-link
                :to="{
                  name: 'dashboard-' + pageActive + '-edit',
                  params: { edit: rows[props.index][slug] },
                }"
                class="cursor-pointer"
                ><svg
                  class="w-6 h-6"
                  fill="none"
                  stroke="currentColor"
                  viewBox="0 0 24 24"
                  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                >
                  <path
                    stroke-linecap="round"
                    stroke-linejoin="round"
                    stroke-width="2"
                    d="M15.232 5.232l3.536 3.536m-2.036-5.036a2.5 2.5 0 113.536 3.536L6.5 21.036H3v-3.572L16.732 3.732z"
                  ></path>
                </svg>
              </nuxt-link>
            </div>
            <div
              class="flex flex-auto justify-center content-center"
              v-if="pageActive == 'products'"
            >
              <button
                @click="deleteItem(rows[props.index][slug])"
                class="cursor-pointer btn-delete"
                :id="rows[props.index][slug]"
              >
                <svg
                  class="w-6 h-6"
                  fill="none"
                  stroke="currentColor"
                  viewBox="0 0 24 24"
                  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                >
                  <path
                    stroke-linecap="round"
                    stroke-linejoin="round"
                    stroke-width="2"
                    d="M19 7l-.867 12.142A2 2 0 0116.138 21H7.862a2 2 0 01-1.995-1.858L5 7m5 4v6m4-6v6m1-10V4a1 1 0 00-1-1h-4a1 1 0 00-1 1v3M4 7h16"
                  ></path>
                </svg>
              </button>
              <div
                style="display: none;"
                :id="'delete-' + rows[props.index][slug]"
                class="alert-delete"
              >
                <AlertDelete
                  :deleteSlug="deleteSlug"
                  @clickDelete="confirmDeleteItem"
                  @clickCancel="cancelDeleteItem"
                />
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </span>
        <span v-else>
          {{ props.formattedRow[props.column.field] }}
        </span>
      </template>
    </vue-good-table>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Vue from 'vue';
import VueGoodTablePlugin from 'vue-good-table';

// import the styles
import 'vue-good-table/dist/vue-good-table.css';

Vue.use(VueGoodTablePlugin);
export default {
  name: 'VueTable',
  props: {
    endpoint: {},
    slug: {},
    columns: {
      type: Array,
    },
  },
  data() {
    return {
      isLoading: false,
      rows: [],
      totalRecords: 0,
      serverParams: {
        // columnFilters: {},
        searchTerm: '',
        page: 1,
        perPage: 10,
      },
      showAlert: false,
      deleteSlug: '',
      pageActive: '',
    };
  },
  mounted() {
    let segments = location.pathname.split('/');
    this.pageActive = segments[2];
    this.loadItems();
  },
  methods: {
    updateParams(newProps) {
      this.serverParams = Object.assign({}, this.serverParams, newProps);
    },

    onPageChange(params) {
      this.updateParams({ page: params.currentPage });
      this.loadItems();
    },

    onPerPageChange(params) {
      this.updateParams({ perPage: params.currentPerPage });
      this.loadItems();
    },

    onColumnFilter(params) {
      this.updateParams(params);
      this.loadItems();
    },

    onSearch(params) {
      this.serverParams.searchTerm = params.searchTerm;
      this.loadItems();
    },

    // load items is what brings back the rows from server
    loadItems() {
      const data = new FormData();
      data.append('searchTerm', this.serverParams.searchTerm);
      data.append('per_page', this.serverParams.perPage);
      //   console.log(this.serverParams.searchTerm);
      this.$axios
        .post(`${this.endpoint}?page=` + this.serverParams.page, data, {
          headers: {
            Authorization: 'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem('token'),
          },
        })
        .then(response => {
          this.totalRecords = response.data.total;
          this.rows = response.data.data;
          console.log(response.data.data);
        });
    },
    resetStyle() {
      var alertDelete = document.getElementsByClassName('alert-delete');
      for (var i = 0; i < alertDelete.length; i += 1) {
        alertDelete[i].style.display = 'none';
      }
      var btnDelete = document.getElementsByClassName('btn-delete');
      for (var i = 0; i < btnDelete.length; i += 1) {
        btnDelete[i].style.display = 'block';
      }
    },

    deleteItem(deleteSlug) {
      this.resetStyle();
      this.showAlert = !this.showAlert;
      this.deleteSlug = deleteSlug;
      document.getElementById(deleteSlug).style.display = 'none';
      document.getElementById('delete-' + deleteSlug).style.display = 'block';
    },

    async confirmDeleteItem(deleteSlug) {
      try {
        await this.$axios
          .delete(`api/${this.pageActive}/delete/${deleteSlug}`, {
            headers: {
              Authorization: 'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem('token'),
            },
          })
          .then(res => {
            this.resetStyle();
            this.$axios
              .$get(`api/${this.pageActive}`, {
                headers: {
                  Authorization: 'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem('token'),
                },
              })
              .then(response => {
                // assign response to state "products"
                location.reload();
              })
              .catch(error => {
                console.error(error);
              });
          });
      } catch (e) {
        console.log(e.response);
      }
    },
    async cancelDeleteItem(deleteSlug) {
      this.resetStyle();
      this.showAlert = !this.showAlert;
      this.deleteSlug = '';
      document.getElementById(deleteSlug).style.display = 'block';
      document.getElementById('delete-' + deleteSlug).style.display = 'none';
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

pages/dashboard/orders/index.vue

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div class="container px-6 mx-auto grid">
      <h2 class="my-6 text-2xl font-semibold text-gray-700 dark:text-gray-200">
        Order
      </h2>
      <div class="w-full overflow-hidden rounded-lg shadow-xs">
        <div class="w-full overflow-x-auto">
          <client-only>
            <VueGoodTable
              endpoint="api/orders"
              slug="merchant_ref"
              :columns="[
                {
                  label: 'Kode Invoice',
                  field: 'merchant_ref',
                },
                {
                  label: 'Nama',
                  field: 'customer_name',
                },
                {
                  label: 'Kode Resi',
                  field: 'receipt_code',
                },
                {
                  label: 'Tanggal Order',
                  field: 'timestamp.created_at',
                },
                {
                  label: 'Status',
                  field: 'status',
                },
                {
                  label: 'Action',
                  field: 'action',
                },
              ]"
            />
          </client-only>
        </div>
        <div
          class="grid px-4 py-3 text-xs font-semibold tracking-wide text-gray-500 uppercase border-t dark:border-gray-700 bg-gray-50 sm:grid-cols-9 dark:text-gray-400 dark:bg-gray-800"
        ></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  layout: 'dashboard',
};
</script>
```

I'm not sure if it is error from Vercel build because I didn't found any error in my Vercel's log. Thanks

**Edit**

After I build my app in local like kissu said, It's show an error too. What is different between development and production?

Comment: Does it work if you build it locally?

Comment: oh, why I didn't think about that. It doesn't work locally

Comment: The dev server is not exactly what is running on production, it can avoid some errors due to the way it runs. This is why, trying a build often is recommended to spot the build fails ASAP. Not sure what is buggy here, maybe try to comment out or find some useful line in the stacktrace.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I changed my component like basic example of vue-good-table but still error on production. So confusing

Comment: Maybe it's just working poorly with SSR? Maybe give a try [to this](https://github.com/xaksis/vue-good-table/issues/597#issuecomment-953136446) or try to  [dynamically import](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67825061/8816585) the `vue-good-table` to see if it behaves better.