# Nuxt local import client only

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js, vue-plyr

I'm trying to use [VuePlyr](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-plyr) in Nuxt 2. Right now I have it working as a plugin `/plugins/vue-plyr.js`,

```js
import Vue from 'vue'
import VuePlyr from '@skjnldsv/vue-plyr'
import 'vue-plyr/dist/vue-plyr.css'

Vue.use(VuePlyr)
```

but it is just used in one page, so I would like to remove it from the main bundle and just import it locally when used. I've tried this in my page (the template part was working when using the plugin).

```html
<template>
  <client-only>
    <vue-plyr>
      <div data-plyr-provider="vimeo" :data-plyr-embed-id="id" />
    </vue-plyr>
  </client-only>
</template>

<script>
import 'vue-plyr/dist/vue-plyr.css'
import Vue from 'vue'

export default {

  async mounted () {
    const VuePlyr = await import('@skjnldsv/vue-plyr')
    Vue.use(VuePlyr)
  }
}
</script>
```

but unfortunately, I'm getting this error

```
[Vue warn]: Unknown custom element: <vue-plyr> - did you register the component correctly?
```

Any idea how I could achieve this? Related with [How to make a dynamic import in Nuxt?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67824862/how-to-make-a-dynamic-import-in-nuxt)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could import it like that

```js
export default {
  components: {
    [process.client && 'VuePlyr']: () => import('@skjnldsv/vue-plyr'),
  }
}
```

As mentioned in a [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67751550/8816585).

Comment: how would one do this with <script setup>?

Comment: @semkeijsper you don't need to explicitly define your components in `script setup`, so you only need to make the check + import. Feel free to open a new question.

Comment: FIgured it out. I needed it for an SSR-incompatible library, in my case `@arcgis/core`. Import would look like this: `const VuePlyr = defineAsyncComponent(() => import("@skjnldsv/vue-plyr"));` Of course, wrap it inside an if statement checking `process.client`. Thx!

Comment: @semkeijsper yes indeed, I had the same case yesterday with Nuxt3. Great catch!

Answer (score 1):

In your nuxt config define the plugin as client only:

```
plugins: [
    { src: "~/plugins/vue-plyr.js", mode: "client" }
],
```

Then also make sure there's a client-only tag around the use of the component:

```
<template>
  <client-only>
    <vue-plyr>
      <div data-plyr-provider="vimeo" :data-plyr-embed-id="id" />
    </vue-plyr>
  </client-only>
</template>
```

Edit: importing the component again in the mounted method isn't necessary if you added it as a plugin

Comment: OP told about a local import, not a global one, hence the `plugin` option is not a good one.

Comment: Yep, this is exactly my setup now. It works fine, but adds lots of Kb to the bundle, that's what I'm trying to avoid.