# Client-only Nuxt 3 Vue plugin

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, nuxtjs3

I am new to Nuxt and Vue, so go easy on me. I am trying to create a video player component in my Nuxt 3 app using [vue3-video-player](https://github.com/LarchLiu/vue3-video-player), which doesn't seem to support SSR based on the following error I get when I import it in my video component:

`ReferenceError: navigator is not defined`

This error persists even if the component is wrapped with `<ClientOnly>`. So, based on what I saw in the [Nuxt 3 Documentation](https://v3.nuxtjs.org/guide/directory-structure/plugins) I thought I would create a client-only plugin located at `plugins/vue3-video-player.client.js` with the following contents:

```js
import Vue3VideoPlayer from '@cloudgeek/vue3-video-player'

export default defineNuxtPlugin((nuxtApp) => {
  nuxtApp.vueApp.use(Vue3VideoPlayer)
})
```

But when I try to use it in my component as `<vue3-video-player>`, I get the following error:

`[Vue warn]: Failed to resolve component: vue3-video-player`

So I guess my question is how do I create a client-only Vue component using Nuxt 3 plugins? Or is there an entirely different approach that would work better?

Comment: Checked my answer here? https://stackoverflow.com/a/67751550/8816585 (at the bottom)

Comment: So say I went with the dynamic import at the bottom of your answer. How would I do the equivalent of `import x from 'some_module` using `import()` as you did in `components`?

Comment: We have the exact same question here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67825061/8816585

Comment: @kissu your answer is related to nuxt 2, which is completely different.

Comment: @Syffys not completely different no. Maybe a bit regarding the syntax but the issue is the same.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this? I have the exact same problem.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Solution for `nuxt 3`:

Nuxt will automatically read the files in your plugins directory and load them. You can use `.server` or `.client` suffix in the file name to load a plugin only on the server or client side.

For example:

#### `plugins/apexcharts.client.ts`

Everything is so simple! And that is why we love `nuxt` ❤️

---

Solution for `nuxt 2` (to show the difference):

`nuxt.config.ts`

```js
  plugins: [
    {src: '~/plugins/apexcharts', mode: 'client'}
  ],
```

This is only for `nuxt 2` because All plugins in your nuxt 3 `plugins/` directory are *auto-registered*, so you **should not** add them to your `nuxt.config` separately.

Comment: When I use the .client trick I get "Failed to resolve component: font-awesome-icon". Is there some special trick to make this work?

Comment: This is actually highly inaccurate, Nuxt 3 still loads everything you've got there, you get those imported libraries/code in the entry JS file of the production build.

Answer (score 1):

you could try to provide a helper function. As mentioned in the [docs](https://v3.nuxtjs.org/guide/directory-structure/plugins/).

```
import Vue3VideoPlayer from '@cloudgeek/vue3-video-player'

export default defineNuxtPlugin((nuxtApp) => {
  
  return {
    provide: {
      Vue3VideoPlayer
    }
  }

})
```

Answer (score 1):

To tag along with the given correct answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73845421/8862524),

If you're trying to install and use a third party NPM package, and running into "window is not defined" type errors, you can load the package as a plugin as follows (eg [WAD](https://www.npmjs.com/package/web-audio-daw))

> npm install web-audio-daw

```
// plugins/wad.client.ts
import Wad from "web-audio-daw"
export default defineNuxtPlugin(nuxtApp => {
  return {
    provide: {
      Wad,
    }
  }
})
```

```
// pages/whatever.vue
<script lang="ts" setup>
const { $Wad } = useNuxtApp();
// Can use $Wad normally from here on out
</script>
```

Comment: If you have to destruct with `const { $Wad } = useNuxtApp()`, it seems that the plugin doesn't save you much. You can import Wad in the page where you use it.

Comment: Thanks. How would you use params with the plugins fir Nuxt 3? ie `$Wad(param1,parm2)` ?

Comment: now how can i add `mode:client`?