# Nuxt avoid import of client-side script for server-side rendering

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

In my nuxt.js application, I have a script that imports an NPM package which is only compatible with browser contexts (it references `document`, `location`, `window`, etc.)

Is there a way to exclude this from SSR?

```js
import thing from "@vendor/thing"; // causes `document not defined` error
export default showThing(){
 if (process.client) {
    thing();
 }
}
```

I can use the method with `process.client` but this file is still imported in my components.

Comment: Also, if your package could be used locally, do that rather than loading it globally. As explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67751550/8816585

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could import it dynamically rather than in every context.

As explained in my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67825061/8816585

In your example, that would be something like this

```js
export default showThing(){
  if (process.client) {
    const thing = await import('@vendor/thing')
    thing()
  }
}
```